# Ruby on Rails: how does one write a route such that id's are ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

the default route is

```
:controller/:action/:id
```

but I want just :`controller/:action` for my errors controller.

I kinda have this: but it doesn't work, as .connect needs an action

```
  map.connect 'errors/:action/', :controller => :errors
```

currently, when I re`direct_to(:controller => :errors, :action => :ip_blocked)`, it thinks the id is `ip_blocked`... so... thats weird...

anyway... tis a routing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting this route before other routes? If you have any other route that looks for "/errors/:id" it will catch route with `:ip_blocked` and treat this action as an id.

Answer (score 0):

should work fine in rails . it doesn't need an action.

```
 map.connect '/errors/:action', :controller => "errors"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code exactly as you have it in your question in a Rails 2.3.10 app and it works perfectly.  What version of Rails are you using, I can make sure its not a versioning problem.